# My UI is not showing the adapter's array list data if I don't debug

Tags: android, kotlin

It's a problem a bit creepy. If I debug my app, my UI loads the adapter data and I see the cardviews, but if I not debug I can't see the cardviews, like the data is in a thread and is not loaded when the UI is created.

I would appreciate all the possible aid

My project in GitHub

https://github.com/albertbuigues/Touristics

Comment: Please post all relevant information here instead of linking to an external resource (including github links)

Comment: Stuff like this: `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` is a bad idea. You don't need to specify a dispatcher to call a Room suspend function. Suspend functions don't block, so they don't typically need to be called on a specific dispatcher. And by launching your coroutine on a different dispatcher than the default of Main used by `viewModelScope`, you are manipulating your list property on a background thread. Now you have to worry about your Activity or Fragment accessing the list from possibly a different thread.

Comment: It's cleanest to avoid modifying any properties that are shared with an Activity/Fragment class on any dispatcher besides Main. If you only modify them on Main, you never have to worry about concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks, I finally solved it using LiveData objects and calling from an observer in the mainActivitiy and it worked, I had to transform the getRoutes method in the viewmodel to a variable and to not use the suspend keyword. I've not found a clearly info about whats the point of using suspend and Dispatchers.  Now i have a bit more info! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, may be data is not loaded when the UI is created.
But for quick solution you can load data in previous activity and use in your desire activity.